# Css elements with the same auto height

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to have a design based on the following HTML code:

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class='image'><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500" width="500" height="500" /></div>
 <div class='title'>Title</div>
 <div class='content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue, tortor in mattis mattis, arcu erat pharetra orci, at vestibulum lorem ante a felis. Integer sit amet est ac elit vulputate lobortis. Vestibulum in ipsum nulla. Aenean erat elit, lacinia sit amet adipiscing quis, aliquet at erat. Vivamus massa sem, cursus vel semper non, dictum vitae mi. Donec sed bibendum ante.</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class='image'><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500" width="500" height="500" /></div>
 <div class='title'>This is a very very long title longer than a single line, maybe two or three lines... I don't know!</div>
 <div class='content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue, tortor in mattis mattis, arcu erat pharetra orci, at vestibulum lorem ante a felis. Integer sit amet est ac elit vulputate lobortis. Vestibulum in ipsum nulla. Aenean erat elit, lacinia sit amet adipiscing quis, aliquet at erat. Vivamus massa sem, cursus vel semper non, dictum vitae mi. Donec sed bibendum ante.</div>
</div>
```

What I am searching to do is to have two columns (the "container" divs) and to have the "title" elements all of the same height. I do not want to have a fixed height (because I do not know how long it is the title), and I'd like not to use Javascript.

Is there any css trick or css selector that is like "all .title elements have the same auto height"?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify: Are you trying to have the columns side by side and also make all the titles have the same height?

Comment: @linil yes, I'm trying to have two columns and with the .title elements all of the same, minimum, height. The lenght of every title is unknown (from 1 to 1000 chars!). I have solved this using tables, using css-tables and a very terrible markup, using jQuery... but I haven't found any solution for the markup I have pasted in the question (that it is the cleanest markup).

Comment: This is not possible with CSS but is very easy with JS

Comment: I have done it with JS, but I was wondering if there is any jedi css trick to make it works. Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the style below and let me know if that is what you are looking for?:

```html
<style>
 .container {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 200px; /* change as you see fit */
      /*height: 100px; change as you see fit */
      margin: 10px; /* change as you see fit */
}
.image>img{
    width:50px !important; /* change as you see fit */
    height:50px !important; /* change as you see fit */
}
div.title{
    min-height:40px !important; /* change as you see fit */
    margin:10px 0 !important; /* change as you see fit */
    background:#EEE !important; /* change as you see fit */
    padding: 10px !important; /* change as you see fit */
}
</style>


<div class="container">
 <div class='image'><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500"/></div>
 <div class='title'>Title</div>
 <div class='content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue, tortor in mattis mattis, arcu erat pharetra orci, at vestibulum lorem ante a felis. Integer sit amet est ac elit vulputate lobortis. Vestibulum in ipsum nulla. Aenean erat elit, lacinia sit amet adipiscing quis, aliquet at erat. Vivamus massa sem, cursus vel semper non, dictum vitae mi. Donec sed bibendum ante.</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class='image'><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500" width="500" height="500" /></div>
 <div class='title'>This is a very very long title longer than a single line, maybe two or three lines... I don't know!</div>
 <div class='content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue, tortor in mattis mattis, arcu erat pharetra orci, at vestibulum lorem ante a felis. Integer sit amet est ac elit vulputate lobortis. Vestibulum in ipsum nulla. Aenean erat elit, lacinia sit amet adipiscing quis, aliquet at erat. Vivamus massa sem, cursus vel semper non, dictum vitae mi. Donec sed bibendum ante.</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tested your code, but it is not "title indipendent". The title comes from the backend and it is totally unpredictable, and I do not want to have any fixed height.

Comment: is the width of the title going to be fixed?

Comment: Yes. The whole content has a fixed width (it's a column view).

Comment: its proving impossible for me with CSS only. Since you don't want to use JS, the only other way I see possible is that you may have to set the height using server-side scripting by deducing a safe height from the title with the most amount of characters. this may cost you more resources than using JS though. Sorry, I doubt I can be of any more help.